# Apache POI throwing OOM error when trying to password protect modest sized XLSX workbooks (~=80MB)

Tags: java, excel, encryption, apache-poi, xlsx

using java 8 and apache POI and POI-OOXML 3.14

Here's my method:

```
    private static void encryptXlsx(String inputPath, String outputPath, String password) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, GeneralSecurityException {
    //create a new workbook
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(inputPath));


    //Add password protection and encrypt the file
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
    enc.confirmPassword(password); // s3cr3t is your password to open sheet.

    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(inputPath), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
    OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
    opc.save(os);
    opc.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
    fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Error stack is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3044)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3065)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3263)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportStartTag(Piccolo.java:1082)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1802)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseXMLNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1293)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseXML(PiccoloLexer.java:1261)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4812)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3479)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1277)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1264)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:92)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:173)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:165)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.parseSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:417)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:382)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:178)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:249)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:293)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:252)
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:231)
at XlsxEncryptExample.encryptXlsx(XlsxEncryptExample.java:36)
at XlsxEncryptExample.main(XlsxEncryptExample.java:28)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

If anybody could point me to a way to read this file in without using this much memory, a lib that does password protecting better than POI or any other possible sol'n I'd be grateful.

Comment: Side note: 80MB is *not* a modest size at all for an Excel file :-)

Comment: I know, I'm testing with about double the data we'd ever expect to see in prod. It's just that I'm confused as to how an 80MB file is causing an OOM error on a machine w 16GB of ram

Comment: I've verified it with the current trunk and I thought the NIO based POIFS can handle large streams, but to no avail. So even if you would handle the XSSF workbook differently, you can't save 80 mB with 8gB of heap. I'm working on it, but need to understand the mmap logic again ...

Comment: it looks like SXSSF is a streaming extension of XSSF that should be able to better handle huge files but I'm getting weird, contradictory info on it like the SXSSF is a write only format and that I have to load the workbook into XSSF and then convert, which does me no good at all because it's the loading into XSSF that fails

Comment: I've fixed the POIFS issue via [#64387](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64387) - as you've already noticed, after generating the SXSSF temporary file, you don't need to load it via XSSFWorkbook into memory, but stream the raw file directly into the encrypted POIFS.

Comment: wanna make this an answer rather than a comment so I can accept it and get you your fake internet points?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the [documentation](http://devdoc.net/apache/poi-3.13/spreadsheet/index.html) POI normally reads the entire spreadsheet into memory. It does say

> Note that the usermodel system has a higher memory footprint than the
>   low level eventusermodel, but has the major advantage of being much
>   simpler to work with. Also please be aware that as the new XSSF
>   supported Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) files are XML based, the memory
>   footprint for processing them is higher than for the older HSSF
>   supported (.xls) binary files.

It continues to offer low-memory footprint alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void encryptXlsx(String inputPath, String outputPath, String password) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, GeneralSecurityException {
//create a new workbook
//Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(inputPath));


//Add password protection and encrypt the file
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
enc.confirmPassword(password); // s3cr3t is your password to open sheet.

OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(inputPath), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
opc.save(os);
opc.close();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
fos.close();
```

}

Eliminating the call to workbook factory seems to have worked for me. It turns out you don't need to load the whole file to password protect it. Still doesn't solve the issue for anyone who wants to manipulate the contents of a file, however, so I'm leaving the question unsolved.